# Need to understand the use of Generics in the code below

Tags: workflow

```
public class MyData
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
}

public class MyWorkflow : IWorkflow
{
    public void Build(IWorkflowBuilder<MyData> builder)
    {    
        builder
            .StartWith<CreateUser>()
                .Input(step => step.Email, data => data.Email)
                .Input(step => step.Password, data => data.Password)
                .Output(data => data.UserId, step => step.UserId)
           .Then<SendConfirmationEmail>()
               .WaitFor("confirmation", data => data.UserId)
           .Then<UpdateUser>()
               .Input(step => step.UserId, data => data.UserId);
    }
}
https://github.com/danielgerlag/workflow-core
```

Trying to understand this piece of code above.

Line 13 has `StartWith<CreateUser>()` but I don't see anywhere CreateUser type being used at all so whats the use of CreateUser?

and also how do i know what is the object step and data in line 14?

Comment: As you can see in an [example from their github](https://github.com/danielgerlag/workflow-core/tree/master/src/samples/WorkflowCore.Sample01) the Type in between `<Type>` is a custom Type or in this case called a `Step`. So calling `builder.StartsWith<CreateUser>()` Tells your workflow `MyWorkFlow` that the flow starts at `Step` `CreateUser`. On their github there is a samples folder, here you can find some helpful samples on more focused pieces of the repos

Comment: My apologies this is still not clear to me .Thanks for the example link i am trying to read and make sense of it.

Comment: I don't think you should be apologising about not understanding something. My explanation could be unclear. Feel free to ask anything i'll try my best to answer. Keep in mind that I don't have alot of experience with workflow myself.

Comment: Look at the sample at https://github.com/danielgerlag/workflow-core/tree/master/src/samples/WorkflowCore.Sample18, particularly in the Steps folder.